# All conductors exhibit capacitance, inductance, and resistance; does the same apply to memristance?

Tags: memristor

All conductors exhibit capacitance, inductance, and (excepting superconductors) resistance. Does the same apply to [memristance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memristance)? Do all conductors exhibit memristance to some degree? Or is the value of a generic conductor's memristance theoretically zero?

Comment: Does a conductor, were it the only thing in the universe, exhibit capacitance? Or, does capacitance require *two* things?

Comment: One could argue that the ends of a conductor are two separate conductors separated by resistance and inductance, and this have capacitance to each other...

Comment: Every practical conductor has a finite size and thus has reactance. Reactance is fundamentally caused by interaction of electromagnetic radiation with a conductor and always happens on all finite-size materials. Resistance and memristance however are inherent properties of a material caused by the interaction of (moving) charge with the bulk material, so by varying material properties one can vary these electrical properties over a theoretically infinite dynamic range. I know too little about memristance to say anything concrete about this, but fundamentally memristance can exist in everything

Comment: "Until recently, when HP Labs under Stanley Williams developed the first stable prototype, memristance as a property of a known material was nearly nonexistant. The memristance effect at non-nanoscale distances is dwarfed by other electronic and field effects, until scales and materials that are nanometers in size are utilized. At the nanoscale, such properties have even been observed in action prior to the HP Lab prototypes." - http://www.memristor.org/reference/research/13/what-are-memristors

Comment: @PhilFrost  but when do you use only one conductor except in antennas?  In transmission line analysis you have two parallel conductors with capacitance between.

Comment: what's memristance?  never heard of it ... can you include a link and or reference...

Comment: @smashtastic There's link literally in the body of the question.

Comment: I added that in response to his comment.

Answer (score 2):

> All conductors exhibit capacitance, inductance, and (excepting superconductors) resistance.

Yes they do!

> Do all conductors exhibit memristance to some degree?

No. Memristence (if found to actually exist) is a non linear element.  It is not linear time invariant.  Conductors have been shown theoretically and experimentally to be linear time invariant.

> Or is the value of a generic conductor's memristance theoretically zero?

Yes. (or no!) See above.

Comment: I'm still puzzled as to why a relationship between flux and charge is expected to have anything like the other relationships among charge, voltage, current, and flux?  To my mind, charge and flux aren't adjacent corners of a square--they're opposite ends of a sequence.

Comment: maxwell explained this one some time ago with four equations he brought together and were used them to explain how electric charge and magnetic flux are two different aspects of the same phenomena: electro-magnetism

Comment: The basic concept behind a memrister would seem to be that, the integral of current from some time zero to the present equals the integral of voltage over the same interval times some scale factor, plus a constant.  If the constant is zero, the memrister will be indistinguishable from a resistor.  Is there any physical phenomenon which would imply that the constant can be non-zero?  I would think the constant would tend toward zero, for reasons similar to the ones that cause transformers to not pass DC.